# cómo aumentar un número con serialización

Tags: java, serialización

Quiero aumentar un número con serialización pero no logro hacerlo.

**[ESTE ES EL CODIGO COMPLETO]**

**Clase Sistema**

```
package ejemplo;

class Sistema{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*Num numero = new Num(0);
        Serializadora serializadora = new Serializadora();
        serializadora.escribiendo(numero);*/
        Indice indice = null;
        Serializadora serializadora = new Serializadora();
        numero = (Num) serializadora.leerObjeto("objeto.dat");
        System.out.println(numero.getF());
    }
}
```

**Clase Num**

```
package ejemplo;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.swing.text.StyledEditorKit.ForegroundAction;

public class Num implements Serializable {

    private int f;

    public int getF() {
        return f;
    }

    public void setF(int f) {
        this.f=f;
    }

    public void postSerializacion(){
        if (f<20){
            f++;
        }
        else {
            f=0;
        }
        System.out.println("este es el numero "+f);
    }


    public Num(int f) {
        super();
        this.f = f;
        System.out.println(f);
    }
}
```

**Clase Serializadora**

```
package ejemplo;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class Serializadora {
    private ObjectInputStream lee;
    private ObjectOutputStream escribe;

    public void escribiendo(Object objeto) {
        try {
            escribe = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("objeto.dat"));
            escribe.writeObject(objeto);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Object leerObjeto(String nombredelarchivo) {
        Object retorno = null;
        try {
            lee = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(nombredelarchivo));
            retorno = lee.readObject();
            if(retorno instanceof Num){
                ((Num)retorno).postSerializacion();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return retorno;
    }
}
```

Quiero hacer es si **f** es menor que 20, aumentar de uno el número serializado reemplazando **f** hasta llegar al **f=20** y al final imprimir "este es el numero {aquí el numero}"

Comment: Y vuelves a Serializar el objeto una vez modificado?

Comment: si se hace una y otra vez y asi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo crear un método en el Num algo así:

```
public void postSerializacion(){
    if (f<20){
        f++; // el error está aquí estas haciendo primero una asignación en 0, y después a tu primitivo anterior lo estás sumando.
    }else{
        f=0;
    }
    System.out.println("este es el numero "+f);
}
```

Y modificar tu método:

```
 public Object leerObjeto(String nombredelarchivo) {
    Object retorno = null;
    try {
        lee = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(nombredelarchivo));
        retorno = lee.readObject();
        if(retorno instanceof Num){
            ((Num)retorno).postSerializacion();
            escribiendo(retorno);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return retorno;
}
```

Comment: no me funciona imprime siempre lo mismo no se aumenta alguna otra recomendación que estoy haciendo mal @Ajeno

Comment: No había percatado el error pero ya está resuelto. es la asignación de f

Comment: me explique mal quiero que cuando llegue al limite (en este caso 2) vuelva a comenzar de cero y así

Comment: Puedes ser más específico en tu pregunta

Comment: quiero que f = 0 y aumente de 1 en uno hasta llegar a f= 20 cuando llegue a f=20 se reinicie empezando desde f=0

Comment: Puedes revisar si así es tu requerimiento?

Comment: pero no me sirve sigue imprimiendo unicamente el numero 1 no aumenta mas

Comment: puedes poner el código completo de tu aplicación, para poder ayudarte en esto, pienso que es más lógica de tu programación

Comment: ya puse el codigo completo

Comment: Veo todo correcto, lo que no entiendo es Índice es Num? SI así es el caso si necesitas modificar el objeto serializado ve el nuevo cambio

Comment: oops lo siento era algo antiguo el actual es num ya lo cambio